# Unity3d - Change material color of a particle system

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

My enemies have several lives, symbolized by colors.
Blue inside red inside yellow - when a red enemy is shot, the red color is "blown off" (particle system) and the enemy becomes blue - the last part works : )

My problem is accessing the Material of the Particle System GameObject..
- This is what I have so far:

```
    public GameObject explosion;  // particle system from the editor
    private Material xm;          // cashed Material "pointer"

    void start() {  
        xm = enemyExplosion.GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>().material;  
    }  

. . .

    void Damage( GameObject enemy )
    {
        EnemyMove e = enemy.GetComponent<EnemyMove>();

        xm.color = e.colors[e.life-1];  // line 65

        GameObject explosion = Instantiate( enemyExplosion, enemy.transform.position, enemy.transform.rotation );

        if (--e.life <= 0)
            Destroy(enemy);
    }
```

It compiles, but at runtime I get this exception: (xm is null?)

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object BulletMove.Damage (UnityEngine.GameObject enemy) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/BulletMove.cs:65) BulletMove.HitTarget () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/BulletMove.cs:49) BulletMove.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/BulletMove.cs:31)

Comment: [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) should have a capital `S` otherwise it is never called

Comment: Jeeesus I did it again - now it works (with "material" changed into "sharedMaterial") Thank you again : )

Comment: Ups, I spoke too soon - the sharedMaterial really is shared between all instances - Is it possible to change the color of just the current instance ?

Comment: yes .. don't use `sharedMaterial` but `material`

Comment: The compiler tricked me into it... I've fixed it: Change the material-color AFTER the ParticleSystem has been instantiated - NOW it works (and looks great!) but there's TWO getComponent calls for every enemy hit : (

Comment: you can avoid that if you make the type of `enemyPrefab` not `GameObject` but `ParticleSystemRenderer` and reference it via the Inspector .. then you can skip the `GetComponent`